# Salto de pagina concatenado en una variable Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

**Estoy desarrollando un proyecto utilizando Laravel.**

Cuando intento mostrar por pantalla los detalles de un actor, muestra todo en la misma linea de esta manera:

[image: Error]

Esta tomando los 
 como texto y no como salto de pagina.

Esta es mi porcion de codigo

```
    public function getDetails()
{
  return ('id :'.$this->id.'<br>'.'Nombre: '.$this->first_name.'<br>'.'Apellido: '.$this->last_name.'<br>'.'Rating: '.$this->rating.'<br>'.'Id de pelicula favorita: '.$this->favorite_movie_id);
}
```

Yo quiciera mostar cada detalle en un renglon aparte.

Gracias!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es muy probable que estés printeando en blade los datos de la siguiente manera.

```
{{ tu_codigo }}
```

Prueba de la siguiente manera si quieres que "renderice" el html que llega como respuesta:

```
{!! tu_codigo !!}
```

Comment: printeo asi {{!! $actores->getDetails() !!}} y nada

Comment: Una sola llave. No dos

Comment: si, era una sola llave, funciono, gracias